# Parsing powers from strings in Android

Tags: java, android, string, parsing

I have the following code in my string.xml file:

```
<string-array name="accelerationArray">
    <item>cm/s<sup>2</sup> </item>
    <item>m/s<sup>2</sup> </item>
    <item>in/s<sup>2</sup> </item>
    <item>ft/s<sup>2</sup> </item>
</string-array>
```

I also have the following code in my .java file:

```
if(val.equals("mm/s") || val.equals("m/s") || val.equals("in/s") || val.equals("ft/s") 
            || val.equals("km/hr") || val.equals("mi/hr"))
    {
        initiateVelocityConvert();
    }
```

Obviously these two functions don't match up (one is for velocity, one is for acceleration). My question is, how can I make the same function for acceleration, because I would have to parse the 2 out. I can't do a val.equals("m/s^2"). Any ideas? I also can't do an else statement because there are multiple functions, and there are other functions that have powers to the 3.

Thanks.

Comment: put the code where you read "val" from accelerationArray

Comment: How are you parsing the xml?Did you try xpath to get the values?